# Перезагрузка страницы после изменения статуса

Tags: php, magento

Как перезагрузить страницу, после того как аукцион перешел с одного состояния в другое?
Вот код, отвечающий за переключения статусов:

```
protected function _checkPending(){
    /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Date $date */
    $date = Mage::getModel('core/date');

    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $collection */
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('application_time_end', 'left');

    $collection->addFieldToFilter('auction_condition', array('in' => array(self::REGISTRATION_STATUS)));
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('application_date_end', array('lteq' => $date->date('Y-m-d')));

    $collection->getSelect()->where('STR_TO_DATE(at_application_time_end.value, "%H:%i") <= STR_TO_DATE(?, "%H:%i")', $date->date('H:i'));

    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
    foreach($collection as $product){
        $product->setData('auction_condition', self::PENDING_STATUS);
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Везде пишут что через php перезагрузить можно так: header("Location: ссылка"), но как мне указать какую страницу нужно перезагрузить, если код, что переключает статусы, находиться совершенно в другом месте от страницы отображения аукциона?

Comment: Это что контроллер, блок, обсервер? back_url какойнибудь отправлять нужно.

Comment: @Naumov, это контроллер

Comment: Если вы хотите перегрузить всю страницу после каких-то операций controller`е, то возможно вам поможет пара комманд  $this->_redirect('нужный/action');
return;
Подробнее можно посмотреть в коде app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php

Answer (score 2):

в форме

```
<input type='hidden' name='back_url' 
  value="<?php echo Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() ?>" />
```

и в контроллере

```
$response = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getResponse();
$response->setHeader(
    'Location',
    Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('back_url','/')
);
```

в общем как то так.

Comment: код что в контроллере -  это в блоке  foreach($collection as $product)?

Comment: Нет `tataAction()` action который обрабатывает запрос пользователя